# Why won't Catalina install from Internet Recovery?

Tags: disk-utility, install, catalina

I have a mid-2014 15" MBP which is currently unable to install any version of macOS.

I had 10.14.x running and decided to completely wipe the laptop clean. Instead of upgrading, I booted into Internet Recovery mode using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (as detailed [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904))

I then erased all partitions and started the installer. However, the installer wouldn't move past the "start" button. I looked at the logs, and the logs just said that it couldn't convert any partition into a macOS journalled partition.

I then rebooted using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. This boots the Mac into a mode where it tried to set up using Yosemite. While the Yosemite disk utility tool was able to clear all partitions so that I could start the installer, the installation itself wouldn't complete. The error message displayed something along the lines of "couldn't download additional resources."

So now I'm stuck. The Catalina installer won't start and Apple won't let me download an older macOS and get it into a state where I can have a working computer.

The only other computer I have at my disposal is a Windows 10 machine. Unfortunately, I don't think that I can download a DMG for an older version of macOS, say 10.14 or older and start the installer.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of "erasing partitions" as you described for your first attempt, instead choose  MacOS Utilities > Disk Utilities to completely erase and reformat the boot disk. Then endeavour to download and install the new OS.

Comment: I have tried that a few times. It seems to be hit and miss. I had success on the third attempt. But the third attempt finally timed out at the last two minutes of the setup. In the third attempt, I did clear the NVRAM which seemed to do some good.